# Magento2 - product is not showing after data migration

Tags: magento2, upgrade, migration, magento2-migration-tool

I have migrated Magento 1.9 data to Magento 2 using data migration tool. Data migrate successfully completed.

When I log in to admin dashboard that time all product showing correctly.

When I searched product that time product is not displaying in the list page. But I am directly put URL key in front of the domain name that time product is display.

I have tried following things,

```
 A product is set to enabled under a status
 A product is set to catalog (and search) under visibility 
 A product has qty (in stock) and set to in stock
 A product is attached to a category
 Then run an "Empty cache" and a re-index.
```

Comment: did you run setup upgrade and static content deploy command?

Comment: yes i did @abhishesk

Answer (score 1):

Make sure products are added to the website. Same thing happened to me

Catalog > Products | Select All

Then on the Options dropdown, "Update Attributes" > Select the "Websites" tab on the left. Check the boxes under "Add Product to Websites" > Save

Might have to clear cache after. But that's what worked for me. Even though the DB was showing the field correctly, running the update fixed it for me.

I hope it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

(additionally) to this catalog-update you need to reindex the index, what worked for me. In shell use

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```